# Main function input for RealFloat in haskell

Tags: haskell, io, program-entry-point

I am trying to make a main function that takes 2 Realfloat input and pass through this function

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a -> String  
bmiTell weight height  
    | bmi <= 18.5 = "You're underweight"
    | bmi <= 25.0 = "You're normal"
    | bmi <= 30.0 = "You're overweight"
    | otherwise = "You're obese"
    where bmi = weight / height ^ 2
```

And my solution is, where I trying to get weight and height and pass it through the bmiTell funtion

```
main = do
    putStrLn "What's your weight?"  
    weight <- getLine  
    putStrLn "What's your height?"  
    height <- getLine
    print (bmiTell( read weight ::Float, read height ::Float))
```

and this is giving this error

```
* No instance for (Show ((Float, Float) -> String))
        arising from a use of `print'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        print (bmiTell (read weight :: Float, read height :: Float))
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn "What's your weight?"
           weight <- getLine
           putStrLn "What's your height?"
           height <- getLine
           ....
      In an equation for `main':
          main
            = do putStrLn "What's your weight?"
                 weight <- getLine
                 putStrLn "What's your height?"
                 ....
   |
14 |     print (bmiTell( read weight ::Float, read height ::Float))
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

getbmi.hs:14:12: error:
    * No instance for (RealFloat (Float, Float))
        arising from a use of `bmiTell'
    * In the first argument of `print', namely
        `(bmiTell (read weight :: Float, read height :: Float))'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        print (bmiTell (read weight :: Float, read height :: Float))
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn "What's your weight?"
           weight <- getLine
           putStrLn "What's your height?"
           height <- getLine
           ....
   |
14 |     print (bmiTell( read weight ::Float, read height ::Float))
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand that RealFloat is Double or Float. Can anyone How to get input for RealFloat and pass it through a function.

Comment: Function calls in Haskell do not require parens around the arguments or commas between the arguments. Change `bmiTell( read weight ::Float, read height ::Float)` to `bmiTell (read weight :: Float) (read height :: Float)`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you provide me any resource where I can learn more about Haskell  IO

Comment: This problem doesn't have anything about it that is related to IO. I don't have any particular recommendations, but the [Haskell tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info) does have some information you may find useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, I will in the following discuss a *monomorphic version* of your function, i.e.

```
bmiTell :: Double -> Double -> String
```

(For a `RealFloat`, the type `Double` is [usually the only sensible choice](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Floating_point).)

---

Your code would actually work if you had defined

```
bmiTell :: (Double, Double) -> String  
bmiTell(weight, height)
  | ...
```

That would be the “normal way” to define a multi-parameter function, as most other programming languages would do it. In this case `bmiTell (read weight, read height)` would work.

You *can* do this in Haskell, however we prefer a different style that is in many ways equivalent but offers some nice advantages, though it is often confusing for beginners: we [Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) most multi-parameter functions.

It can be explained quite simply: instead of supplying both arguments *at once*, in a tuple, you supply first one argument, then the next. And so on. So, you have the function `bmiTell`. You give it the argument `w`, i.e. you write `bmiTell w`. Then you also give it the argument `h`, so you write `(bmiTell w) h`, where the parser allows us to omit the parentheses.

The function has thus the signature `bmiTell :: Double -> SOMETHING`, where `SOMETHING` must be able to accept another parameter... and only then give a string. So, in fact

```
bmiTell :: Double -> (Double -> String)
```

Here too, the parsing rules were deliberately chosen so we can actually just omit the parentheses.

To use that function, you must, well – give both arguments one-by-one.

```
    bmiTell (read weight) (reight height)
```

In the whole program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "What's your weight?"  
    weight <- getLine  
    putStrLn "What's your height?"  
    height <- getLine
    print (bmiTell (read weight) (read height))
```

Actually we like to omit even more parentheses (we're not Lispers!), which can be done by using the handy no-op `$` operator:

```
    print $ bmiTell (read weight) (read height)
```